# Match & replace 2 specific url's by mod_rewrite

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a working WordPress permalink set-up. I run on Apache's using the following .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I know some old links are being used which are not valid anymore:

```
http://server2.server.eu/~myclient/diensten/overzicht-diensten/
http://server2.server.eu/~myclient/werken-bij/vacatures/
```

What could I add to the .htaccess to have them written to (respectively)

```
http://www.domain.nl/diensten/overzicht-diensten/
http://www.domain.nl/werken-bij/vacatures/
```

Without affecting the permalink setup

PS: I have made the hostnames fictional.

Comment: I assume both domains (`server2.server.eu` and `www.domain.nl`) are actually the same domain? Or they different but pointing into the same website? Or something else? Please elaborate. Except the above -- the rest (actual rewrite rule) is very simple.

Comment: Those are different domains pointing to the same ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^~myclient/(.*)$ http://www.domain.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Doesn't this just remove the ~myclient part? I needed to rewrite the entire link (including full domain).